# How to read a value using opencv camera and send this value by websocket connection

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, websocket, async-await

I created a websocket connection where the client sends a value to the server and it initiates a camera scan with OpenCV to detect barcodes and send the product id back to the client, however when the client sends a message closing the connection the camera reading remains on until it detects a new bar code and only then does it really close the connection, is there any way to end the reading loop when the connection is closed? Or a more efficient way for me to enable reading during connection?

```
async def handler(websocket, path):
  while True:
    try:
      data = await websocket.recv()

      if data:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(3, 640)
        cap.set(4, 480)
        productId = -1

        while True:
          _, img = cap.read()

          for barcode in decode(img):
            barcodeData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            productId = searchProductId(barcodeData)
                
            if productId != -1:
              await websocket.send(productId)
              await asyncio.sleep(1)

              productId = -1
                
             cv2.imshow('Result', img)
             cv2.waitKey(1)

     except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
        print("Closing connection!")
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        break

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: How do you detect a "close" message from the client?  Your `handler` function always calls `readBarcode` because it doesn't parse the data at all.  No matter what the client sends, you always read the barcode.  The loop in `readBarcode` isn't really infinite because it contains a break, and you say that you are already sending the ID back to the client.  Perhaps I'm missing something, but it appears that readBarcode is working.  So why don't you proceed by parsing the data from the client, so that your program can handle a request to terminate?

Comment: Perhaps I have explained this context wrong, when the connection is opened the reader starts and can read several barcodes (like a market cashier), the reader should only close when the client no longer wants to read barcodes and close the connection.

Comment: not specific to OpenCV. async/await has to have general strategies to interface with traditional blocking code. in any case, your async/await code can detect when you close the websocket. in that case, it simply has to *stop using* (close) the VideoCapture. if that doesn't happen, the code needs further debugging. figure out if a closed connection really is signalled by an exception... because sockets usually signal that by the read() call returning 0 bytes.

Comment: Since you haven't explained how the server can know that the client no longer wants to read barcodes, it's difficult to be specific.  Somewhere in your loop you can check the connection for more incoming data, or for a closed connection.  You can do this by calling websocket.recv, but wrap that in an asyncio.wait_for.  If there's no new data, you will get a timeout; if there is new data, you can react to it.  See the docs on wait_for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=wait_for#asyncio.wait_for.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread